# Obtengo resultados diferentes en PHP y MYSQL

Tags: mysql, php7, pdo

Tengo un problema al ejecutar una consulta.

Cuando la ejecuto en MySQL Workbench me da el resultado que quiero pero cuando la ejecuto con PHP me da algo completamente diferente.

Consulta SQL:

```html
SELECT 
monthname(v.fecha_venta) as mes,
sum(d.sub_total_detalle) as total
FROM venta v, detalle d
where v.id_venta=d.id_venta
group by monthname(v.fecha_venta)
```

El resultado que me arroja:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La consulta en PHP 7.2

```html
  $query = "SELECT
      monthname(v.fecha_venta) as mes,
      sum(d.sub_total_detalle) as total
    FROM venta v, detalle d
    where v.id_venta=d.id_venta
    group by monthname(v.fecha_venta)";
    
    
  $res = $conexion->prepare($query);
  $res->execute();
  $data=$res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);   



  foreach($data as $d){                     
     echo $d['mes'].' -> '.$d['total'].'<br>';
  }
```

Lo que obtengo después de ejecutar la consulta en PHP:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y porque no mejor imprimes el numero del mes **enero =1,febrero=2** y haces un array y en 2 lineas de codigo tienes eso sin usar mysql

Comment: ¿Seguro que estás consultando a la misma tabla en ambos casos? Me parece que consultas a tablas distintas. Para saber si es la misma tabla, prueba esto en PHP: `$conexion->query('select database()')->fetchColumn();` y en la BD directamente: `select database();`

Comment: Ya lo solucioné... Era un fallo en la base de datos y tuve que restaurarla. Gracias por sus comentarios